# Extract a substring from a string using PHP (Cake PHP application)

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I need help to solve the following problem.

**I have a input string as follows:-**

> <span class="notranslate">msgid
>   "Default_TOP_01" </span>  <br>  <span
>   class="notranslate">msgstr
>    </span>"home  <strong>page </strong>"
>    <br>  <span class="notranslate">msgid
>   "Default_TOP_02" </span>  <br>  <span
>   class="notranslate">msgstr
>    </span>"content  <span>within </span>"

**The desired output should be:-**

> msgid "Default_TOP_01"  \n  msgstr
>   "home  <strong>page </strong>" \n  msgid
>   "Default_TOP_02" \n  msgstr "content
>    <span>within </span>"

I need the starting and ending span tags with class="notranslate"  to be removed. The  **<br>** tags should be replaced by \n. Any tags withing the "msgstr" value should not be removed, for example  **msgstr "content <span>within </span>"**

Comment: Your example gives incorrectly nested tags, the initial `<span class="notranslate">` is not closed. Is it always the case that there's such an initial, unclosed tag, may it vary, or is this a typo in your question? May there be other cases with unbalanced tags? May there be a case where the msgstr may contain the text "`<span class="notranslate">`" and how would you like to handle that?

Comment: I have closed the initial span tag . Plz have a look on the quetion now.

Answer (score 0):

First run [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the string to replace any occurence of `<br>` with `\n` and then strip all HTML tags from the string with [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
<?php
$str = '<span class="notranslate">msgid "Default_TOP_01" <br> <span class="notranslate">msgstr </span>"home <strong>page </strong>" <br> <span class="notranslate">msgid "Default_TOP_02" </span> <br> <span class="notranslate">msgstr </span>"content <span>within </span>"';

echo 'Original: '.$str;
echo 'Modified: '.strip_tags(str_replace('<br>', "\n", $str));                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
?>
```

Comment: strip_tags would remove all the tags..but as mentioned in my question i dont want to remove tags withing the "msgstr" value. Please read the bottom section of my question carefully.